# PHP detecting tags in url with preg_match

Tags: php

I am trying to add a layer of security on top of my prepared statements by adding:

```
if (preg_match('#[@*,!$\'\-;:~`^|\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]]#i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'script')) { 
    echo 'Cannot do that';
}
```

I tried adding `([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])` into there but it didn't work.
I also tried adding a condition if `strcmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) != 0`

and when i added  into the url, it didn't do anything

any help is appreciated!

Comment: dont tell me you are trying to prevent sql injection

Comment: "add a layer of security on top of my prepared statements". it's better than not having it. BUT, how can you sql inject when this alone blocks you out of curiosity?

Comment: i wasn't aware u were using prepared stats , it look like from your post that you are trying to strip common injectors from your url

Comment: I am working on a search filter where I get dynamic inputs so it's a little hard to work with prepared statements as I cannot predict how many variables the query will include. So I am trying to do somewhat of a work around for both input and output by using the stripping of all these symbols. Will that still be "dangerous"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to validate the URL. It seems that you are trying to prevent XSS - for this you should make sure you are escaping the output, not to validate the URL. If you really want to block requests with html in the url, than you can look at some ready to use solutions such as [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/)

Comment: I am doing both. I validate the url and also clear the output. How can someone sql inject if all of this symbols are blocked off?

Answer (score 1):

The first is the tag you’d like to match, and the second is the variable containing the XML or HTML. Once again, this can be very powerful used along with cURL.

```
function get_tag( $tag, $xml ) {
  $tag = preg_quote($tag);
  preg_match_all('{<'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*?)</'.$tag.'>.'}',
                   $xml,
                   $matches,
                   PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  return $matches[1];
}
```

Matching an XHTML/XML tag with a certain attribute value

This function is very similar to the previous one, but it allow you to match a tag having a specific attribute. For example, you could easily match .

```
function get_tag( $attr, $value, $xml, $tag=null ) {
  if( is_null($tag) )
    $tag = '\w+';
  else
    $tag = preg_quote($tag);

  $attr = preg_quote($attr);
  $value = preg_quote($value);

  $tag_regex = "/<(".$tag.")[^>]*$attr\s*=\s*".
                "(['\"])$value\\2[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\\1>/"

  preg_match_all($tag_regex,
                 $xml,
                 $matches,
                 PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  return $matches[3];
}
```